# What are some techniques for deploying a single page application that depends on a rest api?

Tags: java, rest, angularjs, xss, single-page-application

I'm building a Single Page Application (using AngularJS) that renders data from a REST API call it makes to a legacy system.  This legacy system is very large, written in Java and takes minutes to deploy so we decided it would be more productive to develop the Single Page Application completely separate from the legacy system.

The problems occurred once we tried to communicate with the legacy system's REST API.  Although both apps were deployed locally to the same host, they were deployed on different app servers so I needed to use different ports when communicating.   But because the SPA was communicating to a REST API on a different port, the browsers prevented my requests to protect against [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

We found this build tool name [lineman](https://github.com/testdouble/lineman) (that leverages grunt) that made it easy to proxy http requests.  This got us around the cross site scripting limitation but this was only suitable in development mode.

Now that we've got a proof of concept working, we want to know how we're supposed to deploy these apps together without the proxying.  It's hard for me to find advice on how to do this because Angular doesn't assume you have a backend in the first place and most people that use Angular on the front end aren't using Java in the backend (if that even matters).

We're running into issues like, the context paths of the apps change depending on if they're deployed in prod mode vs dev mode so we've gotta think of clever ways to avoid broken links that work for both modes.  I wonder if/where I took a wrong step here along the way.  Should I avoid developing the SPA on a separate server from the backend?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issues. The URL situation is that you will have different URL paths to your java REST API because you are in different environments.

In order to make these paths cascade down to the angular application, we had to first externalize the base paths in the web app (the app that spawns Angular) to use values that are set during deployment depending on where it is deployed to. We have values in our app servers that link to XML values in config files that we then reference in the application.

Then we create a call from the Angular app to the webapp that spawns it (not the java REST API) that will return the URL that is correct for the environment.

In the angular application, we can then setup the resuorce with the correct base path (the rest of the URL should stay the same from environment to environment).

If you can get the first part working correctly with externalizing the environmental settings, the rest is not difficult.

Comment: OK so when you deploy to production, is your angular app in the same war as your legacy app?

Comment: No. The angular app is an entirely different app as the legacy app. The angular app is essentially just a UI centric app that gets all data from the legacy app once it knows the proper base URL. It gets the base URL from the app that spawned it - itself.

Comment: Then how do you avoid all those XSS issues in production?  Do you run a proxy in production, too?

Comment: We either proxy the calls through the Grails app that spawns angular or we use the CORS solution on the apps that allow the XSS. Idk if that would work for your legacy app, but if not, you can always proxy through your angular web app.

Answer (score 1):

I would put apache in front and use mod_proxy as a reverse proxy to the apps.

Say your REST API is at http ://localhost:9000. If the angular app is only static assets you can deploy it directly under apache. If not you reverse proxy it as well.
For the REST api yoivsetup a reverse proxy for say /api to localhost:9000. So any request hitting the apache at http://some.host.name/api will now be forwarded to the legacy system. Now fix the angular app and you are done.
For local development you can use node-http-proxy which is ease to setup in a similar fashion