# Separate javascript frontend from java backend in build process

Tags: javascript, java, maven, single-page-application

I'm struggling with this for quite a long time. I'm java developer so I know my ways with backend, but I'm lost in frontend world. I know how it goes all this frameworks, build tools and node.js on top.

What I want to resolve is how to separate those 2 worlds, combining gulp, jspm and maven in one project seems to be pretty painful. So my way of thinking is now to create two maven project one for BE and one for frontend SPA. The problem is backend part needs to serve the frontend and here we are.

I'd like to have SPA bundle with the most easier hook in backend just for serving the boot page or something.

I see some problems, the bundle containing the SPA will be big to download at once, is there some other way how to solve it?

Requirements:

- back-end will be Spring
- there will be only java app.server
- back-end will be restful build completely only by maven

Comment: What we did in our SPA project was to "compile" our front end (we were using browserify, uglify) Then during the maven build it was using the frontend as resources. Basically our /* was serving our html and javascript. Then using WS (REST) to query the data. In our maven build, maven-exec-plugin was calling some grunt task

Comment: Probably using assembly and dependencies plugins, right? I was thinking of something quite different. Just make really thin ".war" wrapper around just for serving the content. The pros are separate versioning and deploy of BE, FE. But, yours proposal is more appropriate according the question asked. The drawback of FE and BE in different domains can be seen here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18411078/2944265

Comment: We were using http://gruntjs.com/ to build our FE. the resulting of that build was a JS file, and views (html/css). It was called by the maven-exec-plugin. Basically we had a parent pom. a pom.xml for the FE (which was only to produce an artefact) and another pom for the BE. The packaging of our FE was a .tar.gz archive that we were deploying into the backend. I hope it helped. Let me know if you want me to post an answer